# Specification of ES6 say that we offer Tail Call Optimazation. but?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I had heard about TCO of ES6, but I cannot understand because the code indicated below does not work properly.

```
function sumTailRecursion(n, accumulator) {
    if (n == 0) return accumulator;
    accumulator += n;
    return sumTailRecursion(--n, accumulator);
}

console.log(sumTailRecursion(10000, 0));   // ok!
console.log(sumTailRecursion(100000, 0));  // overflow
```

If Chrome Engine uses TCO, I think that code has to work. 
I understand that other fundamental compilers provide TCO, actually, they change from recursion to for-loop so, deterioration of stack does not exist.
I would like to know the cause of this problem. By any chance do I have fault understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading online about Tail Call Optimization, I found a great article http://benignbemine.github.io/2015/07/19/es6-tail-calls/

The situations where TCO works is:

- the last thing that needs to evaluate before the return statement is a function call
- there is no action after the function call that the interpreter needs to remember to do
- the next recursive call does not need access to any of the local variables in the current stack frame

I think your code does follow the above rules.

You may want to check the compatibility of your browser here:
https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#chrome62

Comment: yes I checked ur link. how do you think that? I would like to hear ur opinion.